# Interpreting an anomalous subdiffusion exponent

Tags: diffusion

I'm studying a process that involves diffusion through a porous film; as such, [subdiffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_diffusion) is expected for this system. My experimental data is consistent with subdiffusion, with an exponent of $\sim 0.2$ (in the Wikipedia notation, $\alpha=0.4$).

The simplest and most general interpretation of this exponent is it describes diffusive ability relative to random walk diffusion. It follows that subdiffusion is slower than a random walk (i.e. diffusion is more "maze-like", with dead ends). Superdiffusion, in contrast, is faster than a random walk (i.e. diffusing species can travel on "superhighways" faster than a random walk).

In general, are there more physically meaningful interpretations of this exponent, perhaps relatable to the features of the host system? Could I interpret the exponent as a measure of porosity or apparent conductivity, for example?